# Load data from flat files in Mysql

Tags: mysql, csv

I am DBA for a django web application project in which I need to load data into mysql from the command line.

There are at least 3 ways to load flat files into mysql:

1. from the cmd-line with redirection, eg mysql ... < table.csv
2. mysqlimport
3. LOAD DATA INFILE

A while back I worked out which method would work in my environment and now have to use those methods again, but found that none of the methods worked.  In part these methods depend on global variables @@secure_file_prive and @@local_infile.  The problem is that even when I set these variables in my.ini on windows, the command-line window always start with default values for those variables.

I searched for all instances of my.ini on my system and copied the file I wanted active to all locations, but still mysql refused to use the settings (it wouldn't even use the local timezone setting).

I copied the file to:

1. the installation directory, ie MySQL Server 8.0
2. the data directory, c:\mysql\data in my case
3. the ProgramData directory, C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data<dbname>
4. C:\Users\All Users\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0

So my question is : Where are the active mysql startup settings maintained on a windows system?

This is a huge roadblock to getting work done, so if you have any insight on this problem, please let me know.

Thanks,
Joe White

Comment: Did you try starting the mysql client with [`--local-infile[=1]`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_local-infile) after enabling it at server level? Or loading the file(s) from `@@secure_file_priv` path?

Comment: The locations for the options file is in the manual here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html Did you restart the MySQL Server service after changing the options file?

Comment: FWIW, the methods of importing data you list are not equivalent. Using the `mysql` cli reads SQL input, not CSV data. The other two are effectively the same. `mysqlimport` is just a cli interface that eventually invokes the `LOAD DATA INFILE` SQL statement.

Comment: Yes, I did.  Only after moving the my.ini to the Mysql Server 8.0 installation directory, and setting the datadir=<path to local dbs> did I get any changes.  Once that was done, I could see the changed variable in mysql.  And after the variables were updated, I could run 'LOAD DATA INFILE ...' to load the tables.  The main problem was the order of precedence in reading the my.ini file.

Comment: @BillKarwin: yes, I realize these methods require different data.  Ultimately, I used 'LOAD DATA INFILE to get the data into the db.  But it was like twisting arms to get mysql to cooperate.

Comment: Feel free to post an answer describing the solution. This is allowed on Stack Overflow, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer